# Possibility of anachronistic fossils due to time travel

Tags: science-based, chemistry, time-travel, earth

In my story, I have a character who travels back in time to Africa just after the [Youngest Toba supereruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toba_catastrophe_theory), about 74,000 years ago in order to collect genetic samples from the human survivors at the time of the most pronounced human population bottleneck.

During her time in the past, she drops an empty polypropylene microcentrifuge tube (similar to https://www.eppendorf.com/au-en/eShop-Products/Laboratory-Consumables/Tubes/Eppendorf-Safe-Lock-Tubes-p-0030121023) that she has been using to store her samples, but as she is in a hurry, dismisses it, rationalising that it won't survive until the modern age where it might be discovered, and won't cause a paradox even if it is discovered.

Would my character be correct in her supposition that her missing plastic microcentrifuge tube wouldn't survive to the modern age and be discovered, or are there circumstances that would allow the object to be discovered sufficiently intact 74000 years later that it could be identified?

To be clear, I'm looking for either "There's no way it would survive, because...", or a plausible scenario in which it *could* survive.

Comment: Storybuilding. Do you want it to survive? Contrive circumstances to rationalize it. Don't want it to? Contrive those circumstances. If you want a worldbuilding analysis, pick which way you want your story to go... then ask. 

Comment: The question as I read it is *would a plastic tube leave behind recognizable evidence after 74000 years?* There's nothing story based about that. They're not asking what a character will do, or how events will play out. In fact the character can be removed entirely from the question without impacting the core ask.

Comment: PSA: The usual term for what the question calls an "anachronistic fossil" is an [out-of-place artifact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-place_artifact), such as the [famous terra-cotta head](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/5/5f/Голова_из_Калицтлауака.jpg) in obvious Roman imperial style [discovered in pre-Columbian context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tecaxic-Calixtlahuaca_head) in Mexico in 1933.

Comment: In *Inherit the Stars* by James Hogan, this is in the final scene of the book. An archaeologist in Africa finds a "space timex" watch in among hominid fossils, but dismisses it as trash or contamination or even a prank by the grad students. Yes though, plastic will survive that long if it is buried quickly and isn't exposed to sunlight or excessive heat. It's unlikely to be found though, or even understood prior to the 20th century.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's organic, so it *might* fossilise if it found itself in ideal conditions for the fossilisation of soft tissue, i.e. being rapidly buried in stagnant, anerobic mud, which later becomes part of a sedimentary rock.

However, even if such a fossil did form, the chances of it being dug up and noticed in the main character's own time are essentially zero. If it happened in a story I would find it really frustrating, as it would be so unrealistic.

The reason is that someone would have to look at the exact right rock at the exact right time. In this case that's especially unlikely, since there would likely be nothing special about the rock at all, except that if broken apart in the right place a faint impression is visible that to an expert's eye *might* appear suspiciously similar to the outline of an Eppendorf tube.

But even if it was a bigger object it would be unrealistic. For a fossil to be discovered it not only has to be formed in the first place (which itself is a rare occurrence), but geology also has to contrive to bring the rock back to the surface for someone to find it. The vast majority of fossils will either stay in the ground forever or eventually be subducted back into the mantle, or come to the surface and erode away before anyone ever lays eyes on them.

Digging up a fossil is a relatively common experience - I've found a few myself, just in our garden as a kid - but you have to remember that those fossils were laid down over millions of years. They're common not because it's common for an animal to become fossilised and dug up again, but because *so many* animals have lived and died over Earth's history that despite how unlikely these events are they've still happened enough times for us to notice. The reality is that entire species of dinosaur have come and gone leaving us only a fragment of a tooth to know they were there, and many more must have come and gone without leaving even that.

So story-wise I would definitely drop the idea of the tube being found. It would just be one of those annoying coincidences that pull you out of the story because there's no reason why that specific thing should have happened at that exact time.

**Edit:** Other answers suggest having the tube be found with the remains of a human. That would make it much more likely to be noticed - but it's still potentially an unrealistic coincidence, because as far as I know we don't currently have fossil humans from 74,000 years ago, and it would be very surprising if we did, since there were so few humans around at that time. However, if you work it into the story in the right way it might be ok. For example: how does the main character know where to even find the humans, if there are only a few humans on the whole planet? Perhaps it's because such remains have already been uncovered, before she travels back. If that's the case then it's much more likely someone would be carefully examining them at around the same time.

Comment: And even if fossilized and the fossil found it would not be a tube of polypropylene. Fossils are not made of organic material. It would be a tube-shaped piece of rock a little different from the surrounding rock. And it wouldn't even be very tube-shaped, because it would be flattened and distorted.

Comment: @AlexP what about a peat bog, so it's more mummified than fossilized?  As for the likelihood of it being found, that's easy...a human of the time found it and made it into a necklace, and it was found with their remains

Comment: @thegreatemu: Peat bog people are what is called *sub*-fossils. They are less than 10,000 years old. And anyway there are very few peat bogs older than 12,000 years or so... We are speaking of a 74,000 years old artifact.

Comment: What would you think of the possibility if one of the people from back then found the thing, kept it with them for the rest of their life, and was buried with it?

Comment: @MontyWild I think if they're deliberately buried the conditions are unlikely to be good for preserving or fossilising it - buried remains tend to get reduced to just skeletons. But here's an idea: what if they press it into clay, either deliberately to make an impression of it, or to make a brooch etc.? It probably wouldn't be fired as ceramics hadn't been invented, but unfired clay might survive in the right circumstances, and the shape of the tube would be unmistakeable.

Comment: That's also a bit too unlikely to survive.  It looks like the answer is that there won't be enough left to find.

Answer (score 13):

Polypropylene fully degrades in a few decades, so unless she dropped it in the equivalent of a lab environment it will be long gone 74,000 years later.

One circumstance which would fit into your story and cause quite a stir is if it was dropped right by a corpse or body part that then fossilised and was found 74,000 years later.

This is because scientists now will analyse the soil around a fossil to help determine it's age and many more things they can find out. The decomposition of polypropylene often leaves some nasty traces in the soil, cadmium and some other things I don't recall, it's rarely pure polypropylene. Which if found would be thought strange and would elicit some niche study.

Comment: There is no cadmium in freshly made polypropylene. What polypropylene has is the property of being really good at adsorbing cadmium from the environment, so that if you leave some polypropylene object in an environment where it can adsorb some cadmium (for example, in a city) and the move it somewhere else (for example, into a lake), the cadmium comes with it. This being a piece of laboratory equipment it likely had no adsorbed cadmium, and any cadmium would have come from the soil on which it was dropped.

Comment: @AlexP you're probably right, I can't recall all the details (if I ever knew them). I just know in passing that decomposition leaves some nasty stuff in landfills.. If it fits the story then just fudge it so it absorbed stuff along the way before being dropped, simple enough to manage I would think

Comment: @Kilisi a major source of cadmium in landfills would be nickel-cadmium rechargeable batteries, which used to be quite popular before someone invented the cheap lithium ones we all use today.

Answer (score 8):

**Frame challenge: I'd rather be bothered with modern microbiota introduced into the aged ecosystem**

Humans evolve, and whatever other symbiotic or parasitic bacteria we have on or in our bodies also evolve, their composition and adaptation changes to human diet or atmosphere composition or whatever. Since your scientist would certainly spend more than a single day in the past, and would not go everywhere in a biosuit (also keeping all her dumps with herself), any bacteria she has on herself have chances to be transmitted to the populace she'll be in contact, and also to the wildlife (hey you touched a tree, there goes a dead skin eater, etc). This could lead to all the various outcome to the populace, starting from their total extinction (the bottleneck was really small, and a person transmitting sickness agents to the entire populace would spell doom) and up to their unexpected acquirement of new symbiota, allowing to say transit to agriculture faster than unaltered, thus accelerating civilization deployment by hundreds of thousand years. Collateral damage also could happen, in case some modern version of our parasites would meet a suitable host in the forests of old, leading to *their* unexpected evolution, hello domino effect.

PS: the girl should also undergo heavy biohazard checks upon return, probably she'll catch some nasty air-transmitting disease back then, and accidentally wreck *current* humanity together with the past one due to us losing immunity to that thing!

Comment: Plot twist - The reason the human community went through bottleneck wouldn't be due to the Volcano, but rather due to the scientist intervening.

Comment: That's not happening because of magic not relevant to this question... but I had considered it, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

I just don't see what is the problem if a small plastic item is found somewhere in Africa. I cannot say for sure, as I have never been there, but I believe that they do have plastic ballpoint pen caps in Africa? (The item looks very much like the cap of a Bic pen.)

But anyway, polypropylene is one of the least resistant plastics to environmental factors, with degradation due to natural factors happening in decades not centuries. I would be very surprised if a small polypropylene ballpoint pen cap dropped on the ground would have survived since Roman times, and really very surprised if it made it through 70 millennia.

Are there circumstances where the small ballpoint pen cap would survive in a recognizable form for 70 millennia? Of course there are. After all, we have fossils of *humans* who lived 70 millennia ago, and human bodies are normally even less resistant to environmental degradation than polypropylene. But I would say that overall its chances of survival are very very small...

Answer (score 2):

For a serious scientific look at the problem of ancient civilizations in the geological record read [The Silurian Hypothesis](https://pubs.giss.nasa.gov/abs/sc07600p.html). The paper can be downloaded for free and has speculation by NASA Scientists about what might remain from the distant past, to quote from the summary:

> If an industrial civilization had existed on Earth many millions of
> years prior to our own era, what traces would it have left and would
> they be detectable today? We summarize the likely geological
> fingerprint of the Anthropocene, and demonstrate that while clear, it
> will not differ greatly in many respects from other known events in
> the geological record. We then propose tests that could plausibly
> distinguish an industrial cause from an otherwise naturally occurring
> climate event.

Answer (score 2):

Frame challenge: Don't bother answering how it survived: There are plenty of artifacts where we don't understand their provenance.

Instead, take it for granted that it survived, then have it match a real-world [Out-of-place artifact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-place_artifact). Optionally, it was disguised as a failsafe against discovery by the natives.